# Stub a function for only one argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, sinon

So basically I have an function whose behavior I want to stub only if the argument is equal to something.
Example

```
var sinon = require('sinon');

var foo = {
    bar: function(arg1){
        return true;
    }
};

var barStub = sinon.stub(foo, "bar");
barStub.withArgs("test").returns("Hi");

// Expectations
console.log(foo.bar("test")); //works great as it logs "Hi"

// my expectation is to call the original function in all cases except 
// when the arg is "test"
console.log(foo.bar("woo")); //doesnt work as it logs undefined
```

I am using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon

Comment: Where do you define sinon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around:

https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/735
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sinonjs/ZM7vw5aYeSM

According to the second link, Christian writes:

> Not possible, and should mostly not be necessary either. Your options
>   are:
>
> 1. Simplifying your tests to not cover so many uses in one go
> 2. Express the desired behavior in terms of withArgs, returns/yields etc
> 3. Use `sinon.stub(obj, meth, fn)` to provide a custom function

I'd be inclined to try out option 3 - see if you can get it to work (the documentation is really light unfortunately).

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. The accepted answer is outdated.

`stub.callThrough();` will acheive this.

just call `barStub.callThrough()` after `barStub.withArgs("test").returns("Hi")`

https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.5.0/stubs/